# How to solve $\sin (2z) =2\sin z \cos z$ and $\cos (2z) =\cos^2 (z) − \sin^2 (z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

How to solve this question?

I have tried substituting $z=x+iy$  but I couldnt get the answer.

Comment: It could prove useful to recall

$$\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} \;\;\; \sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

If you need more help, I suggest including a more detailed explanation (through [edit]ing your post) of your understanding of the problem, your attempts, where you got stuck in them, and the source of the problem itself.

Comment: Try to solve according to the given hints and update your answer with your solution. Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These identities are best thought of as consequences of the [angle-sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).  For example, we know that
$$
\sin(A+B) = \sin(A)\cos(B) + \cos(A) \sin(B).
$$
This formula can be proven either using the identities 
$$
\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}, \quad  \sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
that others have referred to, or using the geometric proof indicated by the first image in the section linked above (though the fact that this identity can simply be extended to complex arguments does require some justification).  Once that first formula is established, setting $A = B = z$ yields
$$
\sin(2z) = \sin(z+z) = \sin(z)\cos(z) + \cos(z) \sin(z) = 2 \sin(z) \cos(z).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging $e^{\pm iz}=\cos z\pm i\sin z$ gives $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2},\,\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$. So$$2\sin z\cos z=\frac{e^{2iz}-e^{-2iz}}{2i}=\sin 2z,\\\cos^2z-\sin^2z=\frac{(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})^2+(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})^2}{4}=\frac{e^{2iz}+e^{-2iz}}{2}=\cos 2z.$$

Comment: I think there should be a minus sign there in the second equation?

Comment: @concernedrravioli There is, in the second squared expression. But $(a+1/a)^2+(a-1/a)^2=a^2+2+1/a^2+a^2-2+1/a^2=2(a^2+1/a^2)$.

Comment: I meant between (e^iz + e^-iz)^2  -  (e^iz - e^-iz)^2

Comment: @concernedrravioli No, because $u^2-(v/i)^2=u^2+v^2$.

Comment: Oh right I completely forgot about the i in the denominator